# How does this model factory know which method to use?

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I am running through a tutorial and I understand what is being taught and the sample code works as described. But I am missing one piece to the puzzle and that is how the factory knows which "create" to use....so I guess I don't understand everything being taught.

In trying to research I came across [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703467/how-does-a-factory-know-which-type-of-object-to-create) but it didn't answer my "how does it know" question as their situation is slightly different.

The _modelFactory.Create(f) is what is confusing me.

Here is the code that is executing

```
_modelFactory = new ModelFactory();
...snip....


public IEnumerable<FoodModel> Get(bool includeMeasures = true)
{
  IQueryable<Food> query;

  if (includeMeasures)
  { query = _repo.GetAllFoodsWithMeasures(); }
  else
  { query = _repo.GetAllFoods(); }

  var results = query.OrderBy(f => f.Description).Select(f => _modelFactory.Create(f));

  return results;
}
```

In the model factory there are two creates

```
public class ModelFactory
{
   public FoodModel Create(Food food)
   {
     return new FoodModel()
     { ... };
   }

   public MeasureModel Create(Measure measure)
   {
      return new MeasureModel()
      { ... };
   }
}
```

Is there some implicit association because "query" is of type Food and the modelFactory says ohhh I'll use the FoodModel because that is the entity representation of food?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
var results = query.OrderBy(f => f.Description).Select(f => _modelFactory.Create(f));
```

the  `f` variable is of type `Food`, since it's coming from an `IQueryable<Food>` instance. So the `Create(Food food)` overload is the one being called.

Really no magic involved, just standard member overloading and overload selection based on type matching of the arguments- [read this article for an explanation of how overloading works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and how you should use it/design for it.

Comment: But to me there is some Microsoft magic. I instantiate ModelFactory...which has NO create..yet it automagically knows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean- your example code has two `Create` methods in the `ModelFactory` class. `Create` is just a method name, not a constructor or anything special.